# Node.js - EJS example

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to use Embedded Javascript renderer for node. I installed it using npm, as given here: https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

And I have the following code, but it does not seem to work:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
 ejs = require('ejs');

var server = connect.createServer(
    connect.bodyDecoder(),
    connect.methodOverride(),
    connect.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'),
    function(req,res) {
     ejs.render('hi');
    }
);


server.listen(9000);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to send something to the response. From the [connect hello-world](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/examples/hello-world/server.js)

```
var connect = require('../../lib/connect');

var server = connect.createServer(function(req, res){
  var body = 'Hello World';
  res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    , 'Content-Length': body.length
  });
  res.end(body);
});

server.listen(3000);
console.log('Connect server listening on port 3000');
```

So for your app you'll want to replace:

```
function(req,res) {
 ejs.render('hi');
}
```

With something like:

```
function(req,res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end(ejs.render('hi'));
}
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 12):

try this: (assuming you have the express and ejs modules installed)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function() {
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.static('./static/'));
    app.use(app.router);
});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('view options', {
    layout: false
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', {
    message : 'De groeten'
});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

and put a view in './views'. call it 'index.ejs' and fill it with some html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
<%= message %>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

works for me!

Comment: I don't know if this answer does - or not - fullfill the original question. But i was looking for a method of passing a model to ejs engine and that shows it clearly! Thank you man! :)

Comment: Same here, very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Set your view engine to use ejs.

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

Now set up the root route so that it will load something when you access your server from a browser, see below.

```
var app = express();

// ROOT ROUTE
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("landingpage"); // use to render an ejs template page
  res.send("hello world"); // to render an empty page with the hello world message
});
```