# How to show the node.js output in HTMLPage

Tags: node.js, webmatrix

I am using webmatrix and building node.js application.
In that i want to pass the value from the node.js to the HTMLPage in the project.

> var http = require('http');
>        var URL = require('url');

```
http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('Hi man');


}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

With that code i tried it gives a page with hi man.Its obvious.But i want this to be rendered in the html page i am having in the project.
How to achieve tat.
Please give some suggestion on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I recommend you use [Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/), which is a framework for Nodejs.

Then I recommend you use [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/), an engine template for Nodejs.

When integreses all, you can use code similar to:

```
...
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.register('.html', require('ejs'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico', { maxAge: 2592000000 }));
app.use(expressValidator);
...
```

And

```
...
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.render('test', {msg: "Hello World"});
});
...
```

Finally in your file **views/test.html**:

```
...
<div><%- msg %></div>
...
```

I hope it helps somewhat.

Additionally review:

- http://utahjs.com/2010/09/25/nodejs-express-and-ejs-templates/
- [Render ejs file in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660659/render-ejs-file-in-node-js)
- [Node.js - EJS example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600952/node-js-ejs-example)

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to request your nodejs server using AJAX and inject the server's response into an HTML element.

Check out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Here's an example using jQuery to connect and retrieve the server response from node running on port 8080 of different host, and insert that into an HTML element.

---

node:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
    //parse the url and query string from the request 
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);

    //if the callback query parameter is set, we return the string (or object)
    if(url_parts.query.callback){
        var str = "Hi man";
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        res.end(url_parsed.query.callback+'("'+str+'")');

    //if it's not set, let's return a 404 error
    }else{
        res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.end('404 Error');        
    }
}).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

---

index.html

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        //getJSON and the callback paramater make us cross-domain capable.
        $.getJSON('http://myotherhost.com:8080/?callback=?', function(data){
            $("#my-div").html(data);
        });         
    });
</script>
```

Comment: this method is fine but in my case node is running in different port.Application is running id different port. So this will give cross domain error.

Comment: You could use jQuery's `$.getJSON` and it's callback parameter for cross-domain ajax. I've updated my answer to reflect.